# Filter array of objects if property value includes the string passed to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of object as follows

```
const myArray = [
    {
     id:31,
     name: "test"
    },
    {
     id:22
     name: "transit"
    },
    {
     id:25
     name: "tomato"
    }
];
```

Now here is the scenario, user starts entering the text, if users enters `t` as input, i will get all 3 objects in the result because the `name` property has text `t` at the start (test, transit, tomato)
Now user enters `to` at the input, i want only the object with name `tomato` in the result.

In order to achieve this above scenario, i implemented the following

```
const propsToCheck = ['name'];
const userInput = 'To';
let result = myArray.filter(o =>
      propsToCheck.some(k => userInput.toLowerCase().includes(String(o[k]).toLowerCase())
      )
);
```

It doesnot provide correct result. can someone please let me know if i am doing it right or if there is any easy implementation to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the wrong way - you should be testing if the input is included in the string, not if the string is included in the input:

```
let result = myArray.filter(o =>
      propsToCheck.some(k => String(o[k]).toLowerCase().includes(userInput.toLowerCase()))
);
```

Comment: As an additon: you can convert the `userInput` to lower case just once before the loop. No need to do that in every iteration.